# Change button text from Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have a IBAction connected to a button in my Interface Builder.

Is it possible to change the text on the button (in IB) from within my code during runtime?

Comment: Do you mean `IBAction`, or do you mean `IBOutlet`?  An outlet is a connection between an object and instance variable.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you've got a button that's hooked up to an action in your code, you can change the title without an instance variable.

For example, if the button is set to this action:

```
-(IBAction)startSomething:(id)sender;
```

You can simply do this in the method:

```
-(IBAction)startSomething:(id)sender {
    [sender setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Or if you're wanting to toggle the name of the button, you can create a `BOOL` named "buttonToggled" (for example), and toggle the name this way:

```
-(IBAction)toggleButton:(id)sender {
    if (!buttonToggled) {
        [sender setTitle:@"Something" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonToggled = YES;
    }
    else {
        [sender setTitle:@"Different" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonToggled = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to create an additional variable to keep track of the button's state instead of just querying the button's text itself? If you insist on using a separate value to determine the button's text then I would recommend using the `tag` property for the button instead of a separate boolean value.

Answer (score 19):

```
UIButton *myButton;

[myButton setTitle:@"My Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"My Selected Title" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  There is a method on UIButton `-setTitle:forState:` use that.

Answer (score 4):

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to toggle:

```
- (IBAction)signOnClick:(id)sender
{
    if ([_signOnButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Sign off"])
    {
        [sender setTitle:@"Sign on" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setTitle:@"Sign off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

myapp.h

```
{
UIButton *myButton;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBoutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

myapp.m

```
@synthesize myButton;

-(IBAction)buttonTitle{
[myButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add if{}else{} control flow. Initialise the button texts for different states at the View or ViewController constructor:

```
[btnCheckButton setTitle:@"Normal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnCheckButton setTitle:@"Selected" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Then switch the button state to Selected:

```
[btnCheckButton setSelected:YES];
```

Then switch the button state to Normal:

```
[btnCheckButton setSelected:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** Use `button.setTitle()`

1. If using storyboards, make a IBOutlet reference.

`@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!`

2. Call `setTitle` on the button followed by the text and the state.

`button.setTitle("Button text here", forState: .normal)`