# Update a Label using NSTextField-stringValue within IBOutlet, takes place only upon return of IBOutlet

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield, iboutlet

will be glad to get some help with the following ...

snippet of my code:

```
- (IBAction)Testing:(NSButton *)sender {
    Status.stringValue=@"ABC";
    sleep(10);
    // ...
}
```

where Status is defined in the `.h` file as follows:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField * Status;
```

// The referencing outlet name between the *Label* in the view controller to the class called *Status*

The problem is that Label within the view is being updated only after the Testing call ends.
(after the `sleep(10)` is done. 
I would like it to be updated on the spot (`Status.stringValue=@"ABC";`).

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the `sleep` command?  It is blocking the user interface, so you don't want to use it like that.

Comment: I wanted to see if the Label is updated where it should or only when the IBAction call ends.
But I would also need to add some 'wait' since I'm planning to do some testing in the background. Do you recommend on another way than sleep?

Comment: Please read about UIKit runloops and view drawing cycle to learn how this works.

Comment: The text field would be updated after the IBAction completes, since that is when the system has a chance to handle events - the system won't be able to update the UI if you block it by doing things like performing tight loops or sleeping.  Not sure what you are waiting for, since the UI is usually event driven.

Comment: "The text field would be updated after the IBAction completes" now this is important data point.
This a Mac OS App that run some tests in the background. 
What I want to happen is after press of a button, I'll get indications of the code execution stages into the view controller.
(it's a test that runs for several seconds)

Comment: When the button is pressed the IBAction is called, so tests can be started then.  The system won't update events though, until the run loop is given a chance to do so (input sources, timers, etc).  Another option would be to write a method to manually pass events to the system, for example using NSApplication's `nextEventMatchingMask` and `sendEvent` methods, and call that when you want the UI to update.

Comment: Code example will be nice...

Answer (score -1):

First I would try this:

Please see this stackoverflow question:[Change button text from Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264546/change-button-text-from-xcode)

Basically you change the button text like this:

```
-(IBAction)startSomething:(id)sender {
    [sender setTitle:@"ABC" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

and I update label text like this:

```
Status.text=@"ABC";
```

Second if that is not working I would try to separate the task into different methods for example:

```
-(IBAction)Testing:(NSButton *)sender {
   //change label text here

   //run another method after delay
   [self performSelector:@selector(methodtoberun) withObject:self 
      afterDelay:10.0 ];

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking to change the label not the name of the button. (I have a Button and a Label in view controller).
I tried using text like you mentioned: 
Status.text=@"ABC";
but I get this error:
Property 'txt' not found on objet of type 'NSTextField'. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe try: Status.insertText(" ") also did you try separating the action into two methods?

Comment: Please post `NSButton` and `NSTextField` compatible code.